# Chrome extension: Open Links On The Same Tab After X Minutes

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

actually i'm trying to develop my own 1st google chrome extension, my plan is something is like that, i have 3 Links and want to open them one by one on the same tab after X minutes.

example :

- 1: Examplelink.com/pageuser

after X minutes

- 2: Examplelink.com/timeline

after X minutes

- 3:Examplelink.com/userhome

after X minutes

- 1: Examplelink.com/pageuser

...... continue

Comment: Start with the [overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview): you need a background script, see also documentation for `chrome.tabs`, `chrome.alarms`.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What is the goal? You'll most likely need to store an array of links you want to visit, either hard-coded or from `document.querySelectorAll('a')`, AND... you need a method for indicating which one have already been visited. You should look into localStorage for that. Also - you should show code you've already tried so we can help you more quickly.